# EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer: cannot map a database table with custom model class

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (3.1.4) to connect to my SQL Server database. I am trying to use a custom model class to "map" to a table `State`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[State] 
(
    [StateID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]    VARCHAR(10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_State] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StateID] ASC)
);
```

Then, in my `MyDbContext.cs`, I declared it as:

```
public DbSet<State> State { get; set; }
```

My custom model class `State`:

```
public enum StateID: int
{
    Processed = 1,
    Intransit = 2,
    Delivered = 3,
    Lost = 4,
    Reordered = 5,
}

public class State
{
    private State() { }
 
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public StateID StateID {get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

When I try to retrieve the list of states via my custom model class through `MyDbContext.State.ToList()`, I keep getting an exception:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'State'.'

The partial thrown call stack is as below:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, bool, System.Action<System.Action>)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, bool, System.Action<System.Action>)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject, bool, bool)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.BulkCopySimpleResultSet, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject, out bool)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.MetaData.get()
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, string, bool, bool, bool)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(System.Data.CommandBehavior, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, bool, bool, int, out System.Threading.Tasks.Task, bool, bool, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, bool)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, bool, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource, int, out System.Threading.Tasks.Task, out bool, bool, bool, string)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, bool, string)

Comment: That exception generally just means that the table doesn't exist in the database being queried. A good first step would be to make sure that the table `State` exists in the DB that you're connection string points to

Comment: @devNull Yes, it does exist in the DB with exactly the same attributes/fields

Comment: Then trace the connection and commands in EF (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3) or in SQL Server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15)